# XAML - Button Content disappeared after giving content through a TextBlock (Except for the last Row of the DataGrid)

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, datagrid, controltemplate

I was using button content as `<Setter Property="Content" Value="Accept">`

Everything was okay till then

but, I had to put a TextBlock for the content since I want CharacterEllipsis in the button content.

Since then the content of the Button has disappeared

and the strange thing is that it has disappeared for all the rows except the last row. Button code for all the rows is the same. Since I am using

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <--code for this column of every row-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

here are the code snippet and a screenshot

```
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Item Desc column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="1.5*" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" 
            IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20 0 0 0">
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource supplyCabinetColumnHeaderStyle}">
                                <Label.Content>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Description" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                </Label.Content>
                            </Label>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" Margin="5 6 0 0" Style="{StaticResource supplyCabinetReadOnlyDataStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--Button Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.7*" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button  Height="25" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" 
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 25 10 4" Padding="10 5 10 5">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Content">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <TextBlock Text="Accept" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DFE0E2" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Gray">
                                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

[Button Content Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OJvq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include `<TextBlock Text="Accept" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>` into button's template instead of ContentPresenter. Setter uses only one instance of TextBlock for each Button. But TextBlock is FrameworkElement, and cannot have multiple Parent (can't be displayed in multiple places) . If you move it to template, each Button will get its own instance of TextBlock.

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Accept">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DFE0E2" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Gray">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```